# How to overlay a flex container with fixed position over another flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This might already be answered on stack overflow, but i looked and followed the found answers but it did not work I want to display **header2** at the bottom of the page over **header**(which i want 100% height and 100%width). If i set those values for header the **Mainheader** is larger than page(requires scrolling).
The following is the code:

```css
.header {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; */
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* position: absolute; */
}
.headerMiddle {
  border: 2px solid green;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.header2 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  min-height: 10vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; */
}
.headerMiddle2 {
  border: 2px solid green;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
.Mainheader {
  border: 3px solid red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Mainheader">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="headerMiddle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header2">
      <div class="headerMiddle2">Option 1</div>
      <div class="headerMiddle2">Option 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Also a Code Snippet on JSbin [here](https://jsbin.com/jeliliqito/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the gist of what I changed in your code:

1. Added `margin: 0` to `body` to remove the default margins
2. `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements sot that the height and width do not exceed the window ( you may want to consider using `calc` if you want to show all the borders)
3. Added `fixed` position to your `header` and `header2` to position them as per requirement.

snippet below:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  }
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
.header {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; */
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* position: absolute; */
}


.headerMiddle {
    border: 2px solid green;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}

.header2 {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    min-height: 10vh;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; */
}
.headerMiddle2 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
.Mainheader {
    border: 3px solid red;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    position:relative;
    flex-direction:column;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Mainheader">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="headerMiddle"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="header2">
      <div class="headerMiddle2">Option 1</div>
      <div class="headerMiddle2">Option 2</div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!